# How to move to second tab and enable the second tab when first tab is completed in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am having three tabs. By default first tab will be opened and remaining tabs should be disabled.

When I completed first tab then I need to enable only second field and respectively.

How to enable/disable the tab by completing tab one-by-one?

```
<div class="Allmenus">
              <section class="mytopmenu">
                <ul class="myul">



<li ng-class="{active:isSelected(1)}" ng-if="roleActor==true"class="myli"><a href ng-click="getActorInfo()">Actor</a></li>
<li ng-class="{active:isSelected(2)}" ng-if="roleDirector==true"class="myli"><a href ng-click="getDirectorInfo()">Director</a></li>
<li ng-class="{active:isSelected(3)}" ng-if="roleSinger==true"class="myli"><a href ng-click="getSingerInfo()">Singer</a></li> 
<li ng-class="{active:isSelected(5)}" ng-if="roleMusicDirector==true"class="myli"><a href ng-click="getMusicDirectorInfo()">MusicDirector</a></li>
<li ng-class="{active:isSelected(4)}" ng-if="roleLyricist==true"class="myli"><a href ng-click="getLyricistInfo()">Lyricist</a></li>                               
</ul>
</section>
                <aside class="myextensionbar">
   <ul class="mynewul">

       <li class="myli"><a href ng-click="showMoreRole()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a></li>   

                </ul>
                </aside>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `$scope.nextRole()` function after saving previous role successfully.

```
$scope.nextRole = function() {
               // RoleNames will have an array of all roles

                var index = RoleNames.indexOf($scope.roleName);
            console.log(index);
            //add this after save success
            if(index<RoleNames.length-1){
              $scope.roleName = RoleNames[index+1];
              console.log( $scope.roleName);
                console.log($scope.indexValue);
                $scope.displaySelectedRole($scope.roleName, index+1); // will set the index value as active
            }
            else{
              $scope.roleName = RoleNames[0];//will go back to actor form or add anything you want
            }
            };

<li class="myli" ng-repeat="role in displayrole | limitTo: 10 track by $index" ng-class="{active:isSelected($index)}"><a href ng-click="displaySelectedRole(role, $index)" >{{role}}</a></li> // used ng-repeat to form tab with all roles in RoleNames
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of current step number in a scope variable say `step_no` and disable steps which are greater than present step number by applying class.

```
<li ng-class="{'disabled': step_no<1}"> Actor </li>
<li ng-class="{'disabled': step_no<2}"> Director </li>
...
```

You can apply desired disabled style through css. Example:

```
li.disabled {
   pointer-events: none;
   background: #f4f4f4;
}
```

View example on [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/EkXorasqOyy7fZ48J4vP?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to implement a wizard?

If so, why not use a wizard component for AnuglarJS like [this one](https://github.com/angular-wizard/angular-wizard)?